# Git Bash First time running. Directory \drivers\etc does not exist

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash

How to fix this problem?

```
Directory \drivers\etc does not exist; exiting 
If directory name is garbage you need to update your msys package
```

I tried to reinstall this. Try to add Git/bin to Path. But nothing working... PLEASE, HELP!

Update 1:
I am using Windows 10 Pro. I have only Windows Defender and i have added git folder to the exclusions. But still it didn't work. git-cmd is working, but i can't use mkdir, cd and etc. in it

Comment: How did you install it? Is this Windows or Linux or macOS?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after installing Git-2.31.1-64-bit.exe on
Windows 10 Pro 20H2 10.0.19042 2009

I found that I already have a C:\DRIVERS directory, and I solved the problem by adding an empty "etc" directory inside that one.

[NEW]
Actually, there's much more to this:

1. Before being able to run Git Bash, I had to disable Mandatory ASLR and Bottom-up ASLR for git-bash.exe, bash.exe, mintty.exe, and sh.exe.
2. Then I had this issue here, and it was a bit of a challenge to catch the error message, because the Git Bash window would immediately close after displaying the message; holding down the LMB on the caption bar at the very right moment allowed me to read it.
3. After creating the "etc" directory, I got the prompt and "git status" worked, but other Git commands like "git log" wouldn't produce any output. It took the full-blown change in https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/6#issuecomment-419589599 to get Git to work.
4. However, I'm still getting errors like the following when opening Git Bash:
       ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/mtab': Permission denied
       'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' -> '/etc/hosts'
   and
       rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/01-devices.post': Permission denied

I suspect that this is due to the fact that I ran the installer as adminstrator, but I didn't allow it to start Git at the end of the installation. And I think I also missed running "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\update-ca-trust", which should have been called at the end of "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile".

So, to complete the installation, I run Git Bash once as administrator and start

```
sh /usr/bin/update-ca-trust
```

from it. Now I think I finally have a running Git for Windows!